# Flickering screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Problem:
I have recently(month or about) installed on my computer Windows 10, since then I have some problem with graphic card or smth else.
The problem is that screen go black for few seconds kind of "Black Screen of Death" and then it comes to normal state.

Question:
1. Is there any logging regarding this problem?
2. How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What CPU and graphic card are you using? Also, what display driver is reported in Device Manager?

Comment: HD Graphics 530 in real and reported as well.